# Am I fishing for significance?

Tags: multiple-regression, mancova

If my multivariate analysis of covariance shows that my covariate does not account for significant differences is it wrong to follow up with a standard multiple regression? I know MANCOVA is under the umbrella of regression, but it doesn't give me the extra bit of information I need. I will explain -

This is my experiment: participants hold hands or are alone while viewing fear-provoking and neutral stimuli. Heart rate variability and self-report ratings are taken to assess fear levels in all conditions. A friendship quality scale is administered, as I've hypothesised that friendship quality accounts for the variances in fear reduction - so friendship quality is my covariate. (My primary hypothesis is that hand-holding reduces fear responses).

Everything in my MANCOVA is significant except for the effects of the covariate - that's fine, but the thing with the MANCOVA is that it's not nuanced enough, in that it shows the interaction between friendship quality and the overall measures - but heart rate variability (HRV) is very different to the self-report measures (both can measure emotion, but physiological and subjective measures of emotion rarely correlate). If I do a regression it will show me how friendship quality relates to heart rate variability, and separately how quality relates to the self-report measures.

I would like to see if for an increase in friendship quality there is a decrease in fear reduction - the MANCOVA doesn't support this, but the standard multiple regression shows that it does if we measure fear by HRV, but doesn't if we measure fear by subjective ratings.

I am just worried that this is fishing for significance. If I didn't get a significant result to begin with, do I just leave it at that?

Comment: I don't understand your models, or the nuance you are referring to here. Could you specify your two models in the question?

Comment: I just edited my post - I hope that clarifies it. Basically, I want to see high friendship quality decrease fear responses - the Multivariate Analysis of Covariance doesn't support this, but the Standard Multiple Regression shows that there is a decrease in fear because of friendship quality if we measure fear by HRV, but there is no difference if we measure fear by subjective ratings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tash, although this is a common practice in psychology, this is indeed the kind of fishing you should be concerned about! Here's a reference on precisely this topic:

Simmons, J. P., Nelson, L. D., & Simonsohn, U. (2011). False-Positive Psychology: Undisclosed Flexibility in Data Collection and Analysis Allows Presenting Anything as Significant. Psychological Science, 22(11), 1359–1366. https://doi.org/10.1177/0956797611417632

If, as you say,

> Everything in my MANCOVA is significant

Then this suggests you might have a very high-powered study, and you can avoid the problem by shifting your attention to the effect sizes instead of the p-values. Another potential solution is to split your data into a training and testing sample, build the regression models on the training data, and then evaluate their performance on the testing data. Select the best model based on $R^2$ in the testing data.

Comment: Thanks Caspar! It did feel like fishing. However, although I have no hypothesis for this, I have mentioned in my thesis, and also conducted a bivariate correlation to affirm a well-known phenomenon in psychology, which is that subjective and physiological measures of emotion rarely correlate. Do you think that somewhat justifies doing the multiple regression to further support this? I would still report that there was no association with the subjective reports, but there was for physiological measures. I don't want to fish, but I also don't want to leave out any information that may be useful.

Comment: I see. Proving a null effect is a whole other issue. Ask yourself what you would have done if the effect of this covariate Would have been significant. You would have included it. So you're saying: If I don't find any effects on a fishing expedition, I'm not fishing ;) Maybe it's better to test one model, including the effect of the covariate, and reporting all results including the non-significant covariate. This can be done in your final regression model, as well. PS if my answer was useful, please mark it as such!

Comment: Thanks for all your help Caspar :) I marked it as useful, but it won't show up publicly because of my low reputation.

Comment: Nevermind, I confused two questions :)